# Conditionally use different Angular Animation on same *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a data entry wizard with BACK and NEXT buttons in the footer.
Each step in the wizard is in an *ngIf, and the BACK and NEXT buttons simply change a property which controls which *ngIf is on screen. like so:

```
<!-- BEGIN STEP 1 -->
<div *ngIf="activeStepIs('step1')" [@slideInFromRight]>
  <input [(ngModel)]="name">
</div>
<!-- END STEP 1 -->

<!-- BEGIN STEP 2 -->
<div *ngIf="activeStepIs('step2')" [@slideInFromRight]>
  <input [(ngModel)]="location">
</div>
<!-- END STEP 2 -->
```

I have an Angular Animation which makes the current step slide off screen to the left and the next step slide in from the right when the user clicks the NEXT button.

```
animations: [
trigger('slideInFromRight', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}),
    animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('200ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
  ])
])
```

]

I would like to do the reverse animation when the user clicks the BACK button. Ya know, so when they click NEXT it slides in from the right and when they click BACK it slides in from the left. I can animate both, no problem there, but I don't know how to apply 2 different Angular Animation to the same *ngIf and conditionally decide which one should activate.